# GPS locations are not retrieved properly

Tags: android

Im new to android development and i understand the android activity life cycle. Please see the following code.

```
    public class MyTest extends Activity{

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cont = getApplicationContext();
        final MyLocation my_loc = new MyLocation ();
        my_loc.initialize(cont);

        myMethod();
        }

    Public void myMethod()
    {
       //here when I retrieve the values, it always shows 0.0.
    }
}

    public class MyLocation implements LocationListener {
        public double user_lat;
        public double user_lng;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private Context ctx;

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            user_lat = location.getLatitude();
            user_lng = location.getLongitude();     

            //here i save the values for constands to use in myMethod                           
            }
        }

        public void initialize(Context context) {
            this.ctx = context;
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, this);
        } 
}
```

Why is it that i cannot initialize GPS and retrieve long and lat values in the same activity?

Comment: when you move your device for a shart distance then automatically triggered the onChangeLocation() method. And get lat and long according this new location.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly does not work? (Exception, no callback, ...)
And: Have you declared the appropriate permissions in the Manifest file?

Comment: @sunil and Patrick As soon as i launch my activity the GPS should initialize and get the GPS coordinates because i will be using them in myMethod. I cant take the device around for it to trigger onLocationChanged method to get the values right? app loads in matter of seconds. why do i get 0.0 for long and lat using my code?

Comment: Because your device have no lat and long right now. once you move and called onchange the your device get the right lat and long and stored in device till the last lat and long

Comment: @sunil question is, how practical is it for the user to take the device around for it to get the GPS locations? Why cant we get the current long and lat as soon as i initialize MyLocation ?

Comment: There is a method for lastKnownLoaction() . This method return tha latest update which is stored in device. If it has no update then it return 0.0 . In that case call location change to move your device. Now your device store the latest lat and long. Then your lastKnownLoaction give theis lat and long. Hope you undersatnd

Comment: Okay i will check it out Sunil. Problem is, as you can see that i initialize the location in onCreate method and then i call myMethod to the needful. so if i debug myMethod i get long and lat as 0.0. If long and lat is 0.0 and lastknowlocation is 0.0 as well, i cannot load the application until i get proper values. How would i overcome this? (Is there a way to call LocationChanged method programitically outside that class)

And why is that i get 0.0 inside my myMethod method?

Comment: Try to use this method: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,60000,10,listener)
when you intialize the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocationClient is the new way of getting GPS. Watch [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc&list=WLRNCZT9Eq_HTG5jIEFxMpdqoXZBNalekx) for complete details on the recent update.

Note that the LocationManager way of doing things is buggy, since there is need to add a lot of code for GPS and NETWORK provider. The new way (internal to Google referred to as the Fused Location Provider) works with sensors to reduce battery consumption big time. Also reduces the need for complex API's and stage wise selection of the **best** provider. Its just 2-3 lines of code and you are done.

With many Samsung phones (Y model including) though there is a specific issue that most of the times they don't return location at all. So you need to kick start that phone to return the GPS. To do that you can use

```
HomeScreen.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        }
    });
```

And then call your `locationClient.getLastLocation` api. As in put the code above, **just before** your LocationClient.getLastLocation or LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation call.

Mind you Samsung is the highly customized android open source product. Google cannot respond to samsung related bugs, and Samsung does not have any android developer related support.

Edit : Watch the video, trust me, without knowing what LocationClient gives you, you wont appreciate the change. You will also learn about GeoFenceing.

Comment: This is awesome @Siddharth. What do you mean by "So you need to kick start that phone to return the GPS."?

Comment: On Samsung phones 'LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` does not return the location. If you call the code (in the answer) above the call will return the location. The code kickstarts the getLastKnownLocation API.

Comment: Put it just **before** your getLastLocation or getLastKnownLocation API. Just before.

Comment: @Siddharth Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that code cause indefinite updates? Shouldn't there be a `removeUpdates(this);` call in the `onLocationChanged()` method to save the battery? Especially if I just need the location once, I don't need to have the `LocationManager` spit out a new location every minute or whatever.

Comment: Nope, 0 does not mean now and forever. I am using it on production app's and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In order to your location question, I would suggest you another new way of retrieving locations.

Check this out: [google play util](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html)

The code below is just a snippet, not fully ;). You dont need to handle gps/network providers anymore. It handles for you, which one is the best and returns a location.

```
LocationClient mLocationClient = new LocationClient(...)
mLocationClient.connect();
...
onConnected(Bundle ...){
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
request.setNumUpdates(1);
...
mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationListener....)
....

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @Luser_K i will check it out. Good if i can get a good example as well.

Comment: Oh yes, I got it by the Google IO 2013 video of Reto Meier... 15:26 min. He explains that really good there: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcNNx2zdXN4

Comment: LocationClient is the new way of getting location from Android. Dont use the legacy way or the one below by @parag.

Answer (score 0):

I made one service for that. It is easy for get Longitude / Latitude using it.

Copy/paste this class in your project.

```
package com.sample;
    import com.sample.globalconstant;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MyServiceGPS extends Service
    {
        private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
        private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
        private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
        private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

        private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
            Location mLastLocation;
            public LocationListener(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
                mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
            }
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.getLatitude() +"....."+ location.getLongitude());
                globalconstant.lat  = location.getLatitude();
                globalconstant.lon  = location.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), location.getLatitude() +"....."+ location.getLongitude(), 1000).show();
                mLastLocation.set(location);
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);           
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
            }
        }
        LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
                new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
                new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
        };
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);      
            return START_STICKY;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
            initializeLocationManager();
            try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[1]);

            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[0]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void initializeLocationManager() {
            Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
            if (mLocationManager == null) {
                mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Copy this code in your Activity when you want to start:

```
startService(new Intent(this,MyServiceGPS.class));
```

Create one class globalconstant:

```
public class globalconstant { public static double lat, lon; }
```

when you want to current latitude and longitude in your project only write this `globalconstant.lat ,globalconstant.lon`

Add `uses-permission in Manifest`

Comment: Still i get 0.0 for both long and lat. I dont think your service is starting properly although i have put startService in onCreate method. Thanks for the code but what is the difference between this and what i have done?

Comment: LocationClient is the new way of getting gps. This is old, buggy consumes 10times more battery and is just not accurate when moving around.

Comment: @Siddharth thanks for comment . you can also stop service after getting Lat and long.

Comment: @parag, what do you mean by stop the service ? should we stop it to prevent something bad from happening ? any side effects to leave it on ?