# Android: How can I get the traveled distance while I'm running?

Tags: android, gps

I'm wrinting a application and I have to show the distance covered while I'm running.
I use the function "public void onLocationChanged" of the LocationListener. When the user tap a botton and start running I want to show the distance he covered updated to the point in which he is located.

I've written this code:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
    if(location != null) { 
        if(location.hasSpeed()){ 
            if(latitude1 == 0 && longitude1 == 0){
                latitude1 = (location.getLatitude()*Math.PI)/180;
                longitude1 = (location.getLongitude()*Math.PI)/180;
            } else{
                latitude2 = (location.getLatitude()*Math.PI)/180;
                longitude2 = (location.getLongitude()*Math.PI)/180;
                distance = (6372.795477598)*Math.acos(Math.sin(latitude1)
                           *Math.sin(latitude2)+Math.cos(latitude1)
                           *Math.cos(latitude2)*Math.cos(longitude1-longitude2));
                sumDistance += distance;
                latitude1 = latitude2;
                longitude1 = longitude2;
            }

            tv.setText("Distance covered=" + sumDistance + " m"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Is it accurated?

Comment: Google out the potential ways to do it. People are not going to give you any idea here , if you do not try it out first. We will be glad to help when you have some piece of code to show to us ...

Comment: *I've written this code*  What is the result of that code? ie What is it doing wrong?

Comment: It works apparently but I don't know if it's result is accurated.

Comment: Upvote, you have code, older api's that wont give you what u need. Few people know about the new api's hence upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Just a Suggestion:

- Store the Latitude and Longitude of the start location and the end location when the user clicks the appropriate button.
- and then you could use [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) or [distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) to get the distance between those two geoPoints.

P.S: This may not work if the user will start and end his run at the same point ;)

**Addition:**

Check this [tutorial](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/03/androidcalculate-distance-between-two.html):

Comment: This could work, but I guess you need to set more waypoints/locations. This way you can already track how far you've gone before you've reached the end of your route.

Comment: Your solution calculates the air distance not the running distance! Your solution only works if the person is running along a straight line, which is not the common case.

Comment: Check the link added in the answer. Another option is to collect GPS data using LocationListener every second(or less) and keep adding the distance covered each time till the user presses the stop button. This would probably consume the entire battery if the user is running a marathon. :)
@AlexWien: my answer is just a suggestion. And I don't know what is this Air distance. I used the application provided in the link, and it is giving approximately same distance as shown by google maps on transit between two points.

Comment: in the tutorial, he is not using distanceBetween or disctanceTo. He is performing some calculation to get the distance.

Comment: @Santhosh air distance is probaly not the techincally correct word in englsih;: its the shortest distance between two points. (In german we call ist AirLine = "LuftLinie".

Comment: @consume the entire battery on a marathon? I doubt that: on my iphone i measure distances evry second for 8hours! and record them to file system!

Comment: the new api's do all this with lesser battery usage. but every second is crazy

Answer (score 0):

Recently google has improved its location based API's. They have fused the sensors with the location based api's to share examples of how location can be made more accurate (about 4 times more effective) and consume much lesser power (10 times lesser).

Some interesting links for you to go through will be [this](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/05/15/heres-why-were-excited-about-the-new-google-location-apis/) and [video google io](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc&list=WLRNCZT9Eq_HTG5jIEFxMpdqoXZBNalekx).

SO link for how to use the API's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807986/gps-locations-are-not-retrieved-properly/16811119#16811119)